# Dealing with locally defined functions in Module while exporting/importing

Tags: export, syntax, data, scoping

Consider the following example module:

```
computation[i_, j_] := Module[{func},
  func[x_, y_] = Exp[-i*y + j*x^2]*Cos[i^3*y];
  {i, j, If[x*y < 40, func[x, y], 0]}]
```

I want then export a table with `computation[i,j]` for various values of i,j, then import it and use the resulting functions. This is what I do:

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "data.m"}], 
 Flatten[Table[computation[i, j], {i, 1, 2, 1}, {j, 1, 3, 1}], {1, 
   2}], "MX"]
```

If not quitting kernel after exporting, the imported data works well:

```
function[x_, y_] = 
 Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "data.m"}], "MX"]
function[3, 4]
```

[image]

However, if quitting the kernel, then the system forgets what are all of these `func$2649`, and the imported data does not work properly:

```
function[3, 4]
```

[image]

Could you please tell me how to export the data properly?

P.S. I need to make `func` local inside `Module` since, in a realistic case, without this, I would get interference between the computations within different Module launches. It is also unavoidable to use `Module`, so the toy `Module` shown above serves as an irreducible set of code that just reproduces the issue.

Comment: Could you perhaps benefit from the `DumpSave` function?

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to evaluate all these functions in your list. Do you want to have nameless [pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html)?

Comment: Something like `computation[i_, j_] =   {i, j, If[#1*#2 < 40,  Exp[-i*#2 + j*#1^2]*Cos[i^3*#2], 0]&}` ?

Comment: Adding `Evaluate` in the if statement `If[x*y < 40, Evaluate@func[x, y], 0]` basically implements what rhermans commented. Not sure if that is what Op wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may benefit by using [Pure Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#17469)

```
computation[i_, j_] := Module[
    {
        func = Function[{x,y}, If[x*y < 40, Exp[-i*y + j*x^2]*Cos[i^3*y],0]]
    },
    { i, j, func }
]

Flatten[
    Table[
        computation[i, j]
        , {i, 1, 2, 1}
        , {j, 1, 3, 1}
    ]
    , {1, 2}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to generalize this approach for the case of an arbitrary function (including implicit ones e.g. interpolations)?

Comment: @JohnTaylor I can't answer that in general, it will depend on the specific details. If you have an concrete example of a function that you can not implement yourself, I suggest you post another question explaining what is that function, offer a minimalistic example of a function that has the same relevant characteristics as the one you want to use, tells us  what have you tried, and why it doesn't work the way you expect.