# How can I replace the locally defined function inside If with its value?

Tags: interpolation, syntax, scoping

Consider the following module:

```
computation[i_, j_] := Module[{func, fintt, fintt2},
  func[x_, y_, t_] = 
   Exp[-(y^i + j*x^2)*t^3 + -(i*y + j*x^2)*t^4]*Cos[i^3*y*t^5];
  fintt[t_] = 
   Interpolation[
     Table[{t, 
       NIntegrate[func[x, y, t], {x, 0.1, 2}, {y, 0.2, x}]}, {t, 0., 
       0.5, 0.05}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][t];
  fintt2[t_] = 
   If[i > 0 && j > 0 && t > 0, fintt[t]^j*Cos[t*i]^j, fintt[t]];
  {i, j, fintt[t], fintt2[t]}]
```

Let us test it:

```
funcTest[t_]=computation[1,2]
funcTest[2]
```

[image]

My problem is already described in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279292/dealing-with-locally-defined-functions-in-module-while-exporting-importing). In short, if trying to export the content `funcTest[t]` and then importing it after quitting the kernel, the system forgets what is `fintt$3487[t]`, and does not return the function when trying to use it. Let us also assume that:

*1) It is not possible to make `fintt` global.*

*2) The `If[]` condition cannot be put out of the `Module` environment.*

The difference, in this case, is that the *If* condition is applied to a kind of implicit function. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue results from the fact that `If` [holds](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html) its second and third arguments:

```
Attributes[If] (* {HoldRest, Protected} *)
```

This is a desired property - e.g., it lets you write code like this and not be worried about a division by zero:

```
reciprocal[a_] := If[a != 0, 1/a, $Failed]
In[159]:= reciprocal /@ {0, 1, 2}
Out[159]= {$Failed, 1, 1/2}
```

Compare to a function that doesn't hold its arguments:

```
myIf[a_, b_, c_] := If[a, b, c]
reciprocal1[a_] := myIf[a != 0, 1/a, $Failed]
reciprocal1[0]
```

[image]

The error message is printed because all of the arguments of `myIf` are evaluated before being passed to `If`.

So to solve your problem, you need to force the [evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) of `If`s arguments in `computation`:

```
computation[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{func, fintt, fintt2}, 
  func[x_, y_, t_] = 
   Exp[-(y^i + j*x^2)*t^3 + -(i*y + j*x^2)*t^4]*Cos[i^3*y*t^5];
  fintt[t_] = 
   Interpolation[
     Table[{t, 
       NIntegrate[func[x, y, t], {x, 0.1, 2}, {y, 0.2, x}]}, {t, 0., 
       0.5, 0.05}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][t];
  fintt2[t_] = 
   If[i > 0 && j > 0 && t > 0, Evaluate[fintt[t]^j*Cos[t*i]^j], 
    Evaluate@fintt[t]];
  {i, j, fintt[t], fintt2[t]}]

computation[1, 2][2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I may not be grokking what you're going for, but maybe this:

```
computation[i_, j_] :=
  Module[
    {func, fintt, fintt2},
    func[x_, y_, t_] = Exp[-(y^i + j*x^2)*t^3 + -(i*y + j*x^2)*t^4]*Cos[i^3*y*t^5];
    fintt =
      Interpolation[
        Table[
          {t, NIntegrate[func[x, y, t], {x, 0.1, 2}, {y, 0.2, x}]},
          {t, 0., 0.5, 0.05}], 
        InterpolationOrder -> 1] &;
    fintt2 = If[i > 0 && j > 0 && # > 0, fintt[#]^j*Cos[#*i]^j, fintt[#]] &;
    {i, j, fintt[#], fintt2[#]} &]
```

Then

```
funcTest = computation[1, 2];
funcTest[2]
```

Since you've used `t` as both a table iterator and an argument name, I'm not sure if I interpreted things correctly. It also seems like there would be an easier way to do this whole thing, but it seems like you have several strong constraints, so I'm not sure what can be changed.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `Piecewise` instead of `If`:

```
computation[i_, j_] := 
 Module[{func, fintt, fintt2}, 
  func[x_, y_, t_] = 
   Exp[-(y^i + j*x^2)*t^3 + -(i*y + j*x^2)*t^4]*Cos[i^3*y*t^5];
  fintt[t_] = 
   Interpolation[
     Table[{t, 
       NIntegrate[func[x, y, t], {x, 0.1, 2}, {y, 0.2, x}]}, {t, 0., 
       0.5, 0.05}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][t];
  fintt2[t_] = 
   Piecewise[{{fintt[t]^j*Cos[t*i]^j, i > 0 && j > 0 && t > 0}}, 
    fintt[t]];
  {i, j, fintt[t], fintt2[t]}]
```